# Rails to_param - Without ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create param `/users/will-smith`, so here's my code:

```
def to_param
  "#{full_name.parameterize}"
end
```

Parameterize will convert "Will Smith" to "will-smith"

So in the controller, the param won't match the `find` statement, thus return `nil`

```
# User with full_name "will-smith" not found
@user = User.find_by_full_name(params[:id])
```

Most of the solutions I found is by changing the param to `#{id}-#{full_name.parameterize}`. But I don't want the URL to contain the ID.

The other solutions is adding `permalink` column in the database, which I don't really like.

Any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Looks nice, but aren't there easy solution without third party plugin? If there's no easy way, then I will go with that plugin

Comment: Using friendly_id is the easiest way to implement this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a gem called [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). It will give you more options to play with.

The problem with your code is that you need to convert that parameter back to original, or use the same kind of transformation on your column during the search. FriendlyId, basically, helps you to achieve the same effect.

Also, I'm not sure, but you could miss that [gist](https://gist.github.com/cdmwebs/1209732). It contaits lots of info on the topic.